# How can I associate to PNR a ghost tkt in Sabre 360?

Tags: sabre

When I issued the tickets sometimes the system it got lost, I should wait until the tickets show up.
I have been reading all the Manuals for Sabre 360, I could not find any info about that topic.
Please help me with this.
Best regards.